# Android map activity doesn't display tiles

Tags: android, android-maps

I am trying to display a map in an activity and I can't get the tiles to display. Here's my code:

```
package com.codendo.androidapps.studhouseaarhus;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LocationActivity extends MapActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.location);
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);
        MapOverlay itemizedoverlay = new MapOverlay(drawable, this);
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(19240000,-99120000);
        String lbl_title = getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_location_title);
        String lbl_text = getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_location_text);
        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, lbl_title, lbl_text);
        itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);


        setTitleFromActivityLabel(R.id.title_text);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }


    /**
     */
    // Click Methods

    /**
     * Handle the click on the home button.
     * 
     * @param v View
     * @return void
     */

    public void onClickHome (View v)
    {
        goHome (this);
    }

    /**
     * Handle the click on the search button.
     * 
     * @param v View
     * @return void
     */

    public void onClickSearch (View v)
    {
//      startActivity (new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SearchActivity.class));
    }

    /**
     * Handle the click on the About button.
     * 
     * @param v View
     * @return void
     */

    public void onClickAbout (View v)
    {
        startActivity (new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AboutActivity.class));
    }


    /**
     */
    // More Methods

    /**
     * Go back to the home activity.
     * 
     * @param context Context
     * @return void
     */

    public void goHome(Context context) 
    {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        context.startActivity (intent);
    }

    /**
     * Use the activity label to set the text in the activity's title text view.
     * The argument gives the name of the view.
     *
     * <p> This method is needed because we have a custom title bar rather than the default Android title bar.
     * See the theme definitons in styles.xml.
     * 
     * @param textViewId int
     * @return void
     */

    public void setTitleFromActivityLabel (int textViewId)
    {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById (textViewId);
        if (tv != null) tv.setText (getTitle ());
    } // end setTitleText
}
```

And the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
        <LinearLayout style="@style/TitleBar" android:id="@+id/title_container">
        <ImageButton style="@style/TitleBarAction"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_home"
            android:src="@drawable/title_home"
            android:onClick="onClickHome" android:id="@+id/title_logo" />

        <ImageView style="@style/TitleBarSeparator" />
        <TextView style="@style/TitleBarText"  android:id="@+id/title_text"/>
        <ImageButton style="@style/TitleBarAction"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_about"
            android:src="@drawable/title_about"
            android:onClick="onClickAbout" />
        <ImageButton style="@style/TitleBarAction"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_search"
            android:src="@drawable/title_search"
            android:onClick="onClickSearch" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="0LzZr3xWzmR-_Y5oqCuTx5DDPo1w_LUH7WZn0uw"

    />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here's the portion of the manifest file where I declared the use of Google Maps:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

I know there are a few similar questions around here, I've read them and didn't find anything that works for me.

Here's what I did so far:

- run on a device
- use a custom debug key
- different layout, made out of just the MapView
- instantiating the MapView in code and adding it programmatically in order to see in the log cat if there are some errors
- send location events to the emulator

Comment: Sounds like the key isn't valid.  Was the MD5 fingerprint on another machine?

Comment: No, the MD5 fingerprint was done on the development machine. Both for the original debug key and the custom one, as described in the Android Dev guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<uses-permission>` elements need to be outside the `<application>` element, not inside.

Comment: Thank you! That was the cause.